# Transform string column from H:MM:SS to decimal in seconds in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, decimal

I'm a beginner python coder, and I've been working on this for hours at this point to no avail. I have a data frame that has a column with durations formatted like so H:MM:SS '1:36:45'. The leading zero is missing for hours, so I wasn't able to convert the column from `string` to `DateTime`; I ended up getting an error.

As a workaround, I tried to split the column using `str.slice` but that didn't work either. The resulting columns gave me seconds and minutes correctly, but hours was essentially a combination of hours and minutes.

I thought about adding a leading zero to the column, but I couldn't get the code I found for that to work either.

Is there an easy way to do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you have a date column as well? if so `pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time_col'])`

Answer (score 0):

Just use pandas to_datetime, they'already dealt with this for you:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime('1:36:45')
```

you'll get

```
Timestamp('2020-01-07 01:36:45')
```

You can get seconds with:

```
pd.to_datetime('1:36:45').second
```